# How to add variables to custom thank you url in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, query-string, orders

I was able to follow the redirect tutorial https://businessbloomer.com/resolved-woocommerce-redirect-custom-thank-page/

But can't seem to add the woocommerce variables to the url.

I want something like this > http://example.com?EO_ID=M180924-678922&Product_Code=vssx2&Quantity=1&Email=billing_email@gmail.com'

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked code is outdated and don't handle any URL query string. You should need to make changes and adapt the code.

> **Note:** Orders can have **many items**, so to make it work for your case **we use the first item only**.

Try this (you will need to define your URL path for `$path` variable):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'thankyou_custom_redirect', 5, 1 );
function thankyou_custom_redirect( $order_id ){
    // Get the WC_Order object instance
    $order         = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    // Order data
    $order_key     = $order->get_order_key(); // Get order key (if needed)
    $transaction_id= $order->get_transaction_id(); // Get order key (if needed)
    $billing_email = $order->get_billing_email(); // Get billing email
    $order_num     = $order->get_order_number(); // Get order number
    $order_date    = $order->get_date_created(); // Get order creation date

    // Order item data (first item)
    $order_items = $order->get_items(); // Get order items
    $first_item  = reset($order_items); // Keep the first Item
    $item_qty    = $first_item->get_quantity(); // Item quantity
    $product     = $first_item->get_product(); // Get the WC_Product object instance
    $sku         = $product->get_sku(); // Get the product code (SKU)

    // Build your query string
    $query_string  = '?EO_ID=' . $order_date->date('ymd') . -rand(pow(10, 5), pow(10, 6)-1);
    $query_string .= '&Product_Code=' . $sku;
    $query_string .= '&Quantity=' . $item_qty;
    $query_string .= '&Email=' . $billing_email;

    $path = '/custom-path/'; // <=== HERE define the url path (without the domain)
    $url  = home_url( $path . $query_string );

    // Not for failed orders
    if ( ! $order->has_status( 'failed' ) ) {
        wp_redirect( $url );
        exit();
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: So where it has 'M180924-678920' , that is just pulling the order date along with 6 random characters. How would I inject that into the string. You have already been super helpful much appreciated.

Comment: @MatthewLoeffler I have updated the answer… check it.

Comment: @MatthewLoeffler Surelly with some changes… You will need to add a foreach loop, to loop through all order items instead of the first item only. Now I don't know how you can build your query string with multiple items…

Comment: That is where I'm stuck. I know I would have to create a loop, just not sure how to build that in the url string.. or have post to multiple strings

Comment: @MatthewLoeffler I really don't know for your query string requirements.